# Race but don't cancel others

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I am trying to race between two channels and a generator. I do this like this:

```
const { fetchResult, canCancelChanResult, chanResult } = race({
    fetchResult: fetchApi(....)
    canCancelChanResult: take(canCancelChan),
    chanResult: take(chan)
})
```

`fetchApi` is a generator like this:

```
function* fetchApi(....) {

}
```

When the race completes on either of the channels, the `fetchApi` is getting cancelled. I want to not cancel it. `race` seems to auto-cancel. Is there a way to prevent this canceling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
const fetchTask = yield fork(fetchApi, ....)
const { fetchResult, canCancelChanResult, chanResult } = yield race({
  fetchResult: join(fetchTask),
  canCancelChanResult: take(canCancelChan),
  chanResult: take(chan),
})
```

`join` waits for a `fork` to finish. When its cancelled, only the `join` is cancelled and not the underlying fork.

Comment: Wow super cool. I actually have this in a while loop, so I can re-run this race with `join(fetchTask)` and it won't restart that fetchTask will it? (testing now but code is a bit broken so just asking to make sure)

Comment: I think we should do `yield` on `race` correct? Because I finally fixed my code and it seems the fetchResult is always coming through right away even though it should be hanging. Once I put a `yield` it fixed it.

Comment: Yes sorry, race is an effect that has to be yielded like any other effect